# is it possible to create a joi equivalent from typescript interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

so, for now, my code looks something like this

```js
export interface IDCARD_TYPE {
  KTP = 'KTP',
  SIM = 'SIM',
}
```

```
export interface User {
   name: string;
   email: string;
   address?: string;
   idCard: { 
     type: IDCARD_TYPE;
     account: string;
   }
}
```

From that interface, I need the Joi equivalents that would at least looks like:

```js
const userSchema = joi.object().keys({
  name: joi.string(),
  email: joi.string(),
  address: joi.string(),
  idCard: joi.object().keys({
    type: joi.string(),
    account: joi.string(),
  }),
});
```

And this is what I've gotten so far:

```js
export interface JoiGeneric<X> extends joi.ObjectSchema {
  keys(params: { [K in keyof X]: JoiOf<X[K]> }): this;
}

export function joiGeneric<X>(): JoiGeneric<X> {
   return joi.object() as JoiGeneric<X>;
}

export type  JoiOf<X> = X extends string ? joi.StringSchema :
X extends number ? joi.NumberSchema :
X extends Date ? joi.DateSchema :
X extends IAnyX ? joi.AnySchema : // this one can be ignored for now.
X extends object ? JoiGeneric<X> :
never
```

And I will use it like:

```js
const userSchema: JoiOf<User> = joiGeneric<User>().keys({
   name: joi.string().required(),
   email: joi.string().required(),
   // how can I make it so that address field is required here?
   idCard: joiGeneric<User['idCard']>().keys({
     type: joi.string().required(),
     account: joi.string().required(),
   }),
});
```

But my problem is, when defining the `userField` the field `address` is optional.

How can I make it that the field address is required when I create the schema?

Answer (score 0):

If the `address` field is optional, I think it's better to define the field anyway and leave the string empty when not needed.

```
export interface User {
   name: string;
   email: string;
   address: string;
   idCard: { 
     type: IDCARD_TYPE;
     account: string;
   }
}
```

I'm not in favor of optional fields, because they (1) require the developer to write more code to handle errors that occur when fields are referenced but do not exist; which in turn, increases the time needed to develop the code, the size of the source code, and the time it takes to run the code, and (2) produce several combinations of an object, that in my opinion should really be handled as new types.